# Difference between BST and Randomized BST

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree, comparable

I have the source code of BST(Binary Search Tree) and Randomized BST from our professors lecture slides, now I want to test if they are working, by inserting new elements, and then how can I see my results like on http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/images/bstexample.png I would like to print them on console and possibly with some spaces ie:

```
 5
3 7
   9
```

What would be a way to get a node, an inserted element of the BST object and print on console?How can I do this, and what is the difference between BST and RBST, also on this line:

```
public class BST <Key extends Comparable ,Val> extends AbstractST <Key ,Val> implements Iterable <Key>
```

what are the <> for, are the they same like parentheses , I would be glad if you can explain me the code line above.Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<X>` designates a [Generic Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) depending on `X`.  See [the Java Tutorial on Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) for more details.

Comment: How about the difference between BST and RBST?